# Best Practices Using gists with Jekyll

Tags: ruby, rvm, jekyll, gist

Pretty new to the Ruby ecosystem and gists.

I am developing a Jekyll site, and would like to use a plugin I found as a gist. What's the best-practice? Just copy the small plugin into the _plugin directory, or list the gist in the Gemfile? If listed in the Gemfile I assume it downloads it to the ruby virtual environment if using rvm. How should I link up the _plugins directory to where bundler downloads the gist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to copy gist content in a `_plugins/plugin.rb` file. The Gemfile bundler way is also possible ([see documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#installing-a-plugin))